# Redmine Plugin - requires restart after every code change ( Ruby on rails )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, redmine, redmine-plugins

On the Redmine plugin, whenever I do some changes and save it, it requires a restart to showcase the changes. Particularly I'm working right now on `init.rb` which shows the effects on `localhost:9292/admin/plugins`.

How can I change it to whenever I save some changes it will show the results simultaneously?

I've added some code in `environment.rb` but still it doesn't work.

**config/environment.rb**

```
config.reload_plugins = true
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change this behavior. From the [Redmine Plugin Tutorial](https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/plugin_tutorial) documentation:

> Note: any change to the `init.rb` file of your plugin requires to restart the application as it is not reloaded on each request.

For situations such as this it is possible to use [Guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) to trigger an automatic restart of the server when changes to that file are detected. There is no specific [Guard plugin](https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Guard-Plugins) for Redmine however [guard-rails](https://github.com/ranmocy/guard-rails) can likely be configured to perform this action for you.